# How to zoom in out with the Google cardboard

Tags: android, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I'm working in a project with the cardboard from Google. I'm asking if there is someone who have the possibility to help with understanding and creating a script for the zoom in and out with the magnet tool on the cardboard. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Used this code 
@Override
public void onCardboardTrigger() {
if (xyz) {
 //Create a function 
zoom();
    ...
} else {

}
// Always give user feedback
  mVibrator.vibrate(50);
}
```